# Executing an eval function within a function

Tags: javascript

Button on a screen, when clicked fires off a function to take the text from  `textarea` and execute using `eval()`.

```
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<button id="button">Run</button>

<script>
output = document.getElementById("output");
let btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.onclick = codeOutput;

function codeOutput() {
    code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    eval(code);
}
```

Clicking the button I receive the following error in my Chrome console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
>       at HTMLButtonElement.codeOutput (index.html:12)

Comment: I don't see any issue here, maybe what you entered in the `textarea` is wrong?

Comment: What did you put into the text area?

Comment: the code you entered in your textarea must be wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/pz9h7ayv/

Comment: after a quick test, it seems that there is even more weirdness to `eval` than I've thought. Although `eval`'d code can access the local variables inside the function it is executed, it seems that the code itself is not in the context of the function -> calling `return` outside of a function

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){
var foo = document.getElementById("code").value;
return window.alert(eval(foo));
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<button id="button" onclick ="myFunction()">Run</button>
```